# Django: How can I make views accept only ajax request?

Tags: ajax, django

What I want to do is not to allow general POST request, only accept `ajax` request.

```
class CustomerInfoCheckView(View):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # CustomerInfoForm by ajax request
        if request.is_ajax():
            form = CustomerInfoForm(
                request.POST,
            )

            if form.is_valid():
                return JsonResponse(
                    data={
                        "valid": True,
                    }
                )
            else:
                return JsonResponse(
                    data={
                        "valid": False,
                        "errors": form.errors
                    }
                )
        else:
            return Http404
```

But problem is that is shows an error: 
`AttributeError: type object 'Http404' has no attribute 'get'`.

How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Http404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception) is an exception, not a [`HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-subclasses) object so you should *raise* it instead of *return*:

```
raise Http404
```

Alternatively, you can return [`django.http.HttpResponseNotFound`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseNotFound) which has roughly the same effect as raising the above exception:

```
return HttpResponseNotFound("Page not found")
```

By the way, I would create a [custom decorator](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/771/) that checks if the request is AJAX instead of polluting the view code with `if/else` clauses.

You can make use of [`method_decorator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class) function to make the custom decorator work with class based views:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class CustomerInfoCheckView(View):
    @method_decorator(ajax_required)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

Comment: Can this also be applied to function based views?